# How to use nslookup command to check email domains in linux

Tags: linux, fedora16

How to use `nslookup` command to check email domains in fedora Linux?
I used the following command in terminal:

```
nslookup -query=mx com3263@dcs.ruh.ac.lk
```

This is not working for me. What's the correct command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query for the domain part, not the full email address.

```
nslookup -query=mx dcs.ruh.ac.lk
```

For programmatic use, `dig +short` or some versions of `host` have better, machine-readable output than `nslookup`.

Not all domains supply an explicit MX record; fall back to the A record in that case (i.e. attempt to connect directly to the host).